# SQL Server update for special format

Tags: sql-server, powershell, key-value

I have a special data format available in a file.

The format looks like this:

```
(class_type:cmdb),(provider_tag:HP),(external_id:D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91G),(internal_id:010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a82),(OS:Windows 2008R2 64)
(class_type:ucmdb),(provider_tag:IBM),(external_id:D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91H),(internal_id:010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a81),(OS:Windows 2008R2 64)
```

Note: There are more columns available in the file I have taken only 5 as an example.

How can I update this to a MS SQL database using PowerShell,  where column names are class_type, provider_tag, external_id, internal_id and OS?

Comment: What have you managed so far? Which part seems to be the troublesome? Which are already solved?

Comment: Give an example of data before/after

Comment: I am new to the PowerShell, so I have no idea where to start, the input file looks like as I pasted above.

Comment: @vonPryz as of now i have this input file and I know I have to put it in to the DB, dont have any script yet.

Comment: @Opera have you tried my solution? Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

As I am not that familiar with PS I suggest you this way. Take data, put it into prepared query and execute it:

```
#Take content from file
$content = Get-Content D:\PS1_scripts\testing\report.txt -Raw

#Create new connection to db
$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$ConnectionString = "Server=DOMAIN\HOST;Database=MYDATABASE;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=0"
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString 
$conn.Open()

#This variable is here just so we can print out the query nice :)
$n = "`n"

#Query to execute
$commandText = 
(
"DECLARE @t nvarchar(max) ='$content',",
"       @x xml",
"",
"SELECT @x = CAST('<row>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t,',',''),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</row><row>'),'(','<param name=`"'),':','`" value=`"'),')','`" />')+'</row>'as xml)",
"",
";WITH cte AS (",
"   SELECT  t.c.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') as cols,",
"           t.c.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') as vals,",
"           t.c.value('for `$a in ../. return 1+count(`$a/../*[. << `$a])','int') as seq",
"   FROM @x.nodes('/row/param') as t(c)",
")",
"",
"INSERT INTO your_table",
"SELECT class_type,provider_tag,external_id,internal_id,OS",
"FROM cte",
"PIVOT (",
"   MAX(vals) FOR cols in (class_type,provider_tag,external_id,internal_id,OS)",
") as p "
) -join $n

#Write-Host $commandText

#Execute command
$command = $conn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $commandText
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()

#Close connection
$conn.Close()
```

If you do `Write-Host $commandText` you will see this kind of query (I add some comments):

```
DECLARE @t nvarchar(max) ='(class_type:cmdb),(provider_tag:HP),(external_id:D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91G),(internal_id:010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a82),(OS:Windows 2008R2 64)
(class_type:ucmdb),(provider_tag:IBM),(external_id:D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91H),(internal_id:010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a81),(OS:Windows 2008R2 64)',
        @x xml

--Convert text to xml (example below)
SELECT @x = CAST('<row>'+ REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@t,',',''),CHAR(13)+CHAR(10),'</row><row>'),'(','<param name="'),':','" value="'),')','" />')+'</row>'as xml)

--Create CTE with values we need (sample below)
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  t.c.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') as cols,
            t.c.value('@value','nvarchar(max)') as vals,
            t.c.value('for $a in ../. return 1+count($a/../*[. << $a])','int') as seq
    FROM @x.nodes('/row/param') as t(c)
)

INSERT INTO your_table
SELECT class_type,provider_tag,external_id,internal_id,OS
FROM cte
PIVOT (
    MAX(vals) FOR cols in (class_type,provider_tag,external_id,internal_id,OS)
) as p
```

XML we get:

```
<row>
  <param name="class_type" value="cmdb" />
  <param name="provider_tag" value="HP" />
  <param name="external_id" value="D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91G" />
  <param name="internal_id" value="010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a82" />
  <param name="OS" value="Windows 2008R2 64" />
</row>
<row>
  <param name="class_type" value="ucmdb" />
  <param name="provider_tag" value="IBM" />
  <param name="external_id" value="D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91H" />
  <param name="internal_id" value="010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a81" />
  <param name="OS" value="Windows 2008R2 64" />
</row>
```

Table:

```
cols            vals                                seq
class_type      cmdb                                1
provider_tag    HP                                  1
external_id     D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91G              1
internal_id     010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a82    1
OS              Windows 2008R2 64                   1
class_type      ucmdb                               2
provider_tag    IBM                                 2
external_id     D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91H              2
internal_id     010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a81    2
OS              Windows 2008R2 64                   2
```

The sample of inserted data (after pivoting CTE):

```
class_type  provider_tag    external_id             internal_id                         OS
cmdb        HP              D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91G  010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a82    Windows 2008R2 64
ucmdb       IBM             D7SUOVGUST46DTVTEMR91H  010d30454043a6009d04c03482166a81    Windows 2008R2 64
```